# JS filter array with objects by another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Dears,

I have:

```
const a1 = [{id: 21, name: "LM"},
{id: 20, name: "Off"}];

const a2 = [20,21,22];
```

i do following

```
const temp = a1.filter(({ id })=> {
a2.includes(id)
});
console.log(temp);
```

returns empty array, and i do not know why, can please some one help me

Comment: `retuen a2.includes(id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrow functions surrounded by curly brackets must use [**`return`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) keyword explicitly to return from the function.

You have missed the [**`return`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) keyword:

```js
const a1 = [{id: 21, name: "LM"},{id: 20, name: "Off"}];
const a2 = [20,21,22];
const temp = a1.filter(({ id })=> {
  return a2.includes(id);
});
console.log(temp);
```

**OR:** In single line without the [**`return`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return):

```js
const a1 = [{id: 21, name: "LM"},
{id: 20, name: "Off"}];
const a2 = [20,21,22];
const temp = a1.filter(({ id })=> a2.includes(id));
console.log(temp);
```

Comment: Dear,i still get empty array as a result, when i take the cone and put it in my angular app.  When i console.log my array:  a1 = 0: {id: 20, name: "Off", timePeriod: "MONTH", scoreType: "SUM"}
1: {id: 21, name: "LM", timePeriod: "MONTH", scoreType: "SUM"}
2: {id: 22, name: "TT", timePeriod: "MONTH", scoreType: "AVERAGE"}
a2 = [0:20] <- for this i get [] when comparing. Can you please help

Comment: my angular/ionic part of ocde, which makes it not to work:  constructor() {
    Promise.all([ this.rService.getRDef(), //2
      this.rService.getRankings(), //3
      this.dService.getSComponent(this.tTitle, this.Id)
    ]).then((res: any) => {this.getAllData(res);}) }
  ngOnInit() {...} getAllData(res){
    this.calculateRankings(res[2], res[3]);}
  getScreenData(res) {
    res.rankings.forEach(r => {
      this.rIds.push(r.rankingId);});}
  calculateRankings(rDef: any) {
    this.rDef = rDef;
    const temp = this.rDef.filter(({ id })=> this.rIds.includes(id));

Answer (score 0):

You missed returning for filter() to work. Filter requires you to return a boolean which you forgot to do here.

```
const a1 = [{id: 21, name: "LM"},
{id: 20, name: "Off"}];

const a2 = [20,21,22];

const temp = a1.filter(({ id })=> {
  return a2.includes(id)
});
console.log(temp);
```